# Change content of a text node

Tags: jquery, contenteditable

I have a div (`contenteditable="true"`) which contains some text and some html. I'm trying to replace text in the entire div *except* in links with a certain class.

I tried:

```
$('div#text').contents().not('a.selected').each(function() {
    $(this).html(replace($(this).text()));
});
```

But it seems that `$(this).html()` is `null` ?

The test content of the div is `'test <a class="selected">test2</a> test3'`

As output, I want `"test "` and `" test3"` to be replaced with the result of the replace() function, while the text inside the a.selected is untouched.

**EDIT**

there could be some other html inside the div, it can be ignored. if the replace function switches things to uppercase, here are the desired input ant ouptut :

input : `'test <a class="selected">test2</a> <a>test3</a>'`

output: `'TEST <a class="selected">test2</a> TEST3'`

**EDIT 2**

This seems to work, but not when replace() returns some HTML

```
$("div#text").contents().not("a.selected").each(function() {
    this.nodeValue = replace(this.nodeValue);
});
```

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ApgEc/2/

Comment: Same start but different question. I asked about the selector, that is ok now. I just need to change those text nodes ! :)

Comment: @Manu Input is understandable, but what should be the desired output?

Comment: Maybe I should wrap() a <span>, to remove the problem of text nodes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like that?

```
$("div").contents().not("a.selected").each(function() {
    this.nodeValue = replace(this.nodeValue);
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ApgEc/

---

In order to make possible to insert HTML in `replace` function, we need to rewrite the code:

```
$("div").contents().map(function() {
    if (!$(this).is("a.selected")) {
        return replace(this.nodeValue);
    }
    return this.outerHTML;
}).appendTo($("div").empty());​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ApgEc/3/

Comment: return val.replace("test", "<a>TEST</a>"); shows <a>TEST</a>, instead of making a link

Comment: @Manu For sure it won't work, since this is a text node. However, I don't see the need for it in the question.

Comment: yeah I used a simple replace() for my tests.

Comment: Thanks. It works in the fiddle but I'm getting some weird errors with my own text. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

[***Working Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/87HeH/3/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#test').contents().each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.is('a.selected')) return true;
        if(this.wholeText)
            this.wholeText = replace(this.wholeText);
        else $this.html(replace($this.html()));
    });
});
```

Comment: @Manu Strange...where and how? Can you reproduce it in my jsfiddle?

Comment: @manu Okay fixed it, updated link in my answer. Chrome handles text nodes a little differently than FF (I only tested in Chrome before)